# Create a matrix from a list of key-value pairs

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of numpy arrays that contains a list of name-value pairs which are both strings. Every name and value can be found multiple times in the list, and I would like to convert it to a binary matrix.

The columns represent the values while the rows represent a key/name, and when a field is set to 1 it represents that particular name value pair.

E.g

I have

```
A : aa
A : bb
A : cc
B : bb
C : aa
```

and i want to convert it to

```
     aa bb cc 
 A    1  1  1
 B    0  1  0 
 C    1  0  0
```

I have some code that does this but I was wondering if there is an easier/out of the box way of doing this with numpy or some other library.

This is my code so far:

```
resources = Set(result[:,1])
resourcesDict = {}
i = 0 
for r in resources:   
    resourcesDict[r] = i
    i = i + 1

clients = Set(result[:,0])
clientsDict = {}
i = 0 
for c in clients:    
    clientsDict[c] = i
    i = i + 1

arr = np.zeros((len(clientsDict),len(resourcesDict)), dtype = 'bool')
for line in result[:,0:2]: 
    arr[clientsDict[line[0]],resourcesDict[line[1]]] = True
```

and in result theres the following

```
array([["a","aa"],["a","bb"],..]
```

Comment: There is no way to answer your question without seeing the code  you already have.

Comment: What are the exact input format? Do you want to convert sparse matrix into a dense one? (then see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.html)

Comment: Please show the code that "does this"

Answer (score 2):

I feel that using [Pandas.DataFrame.pivot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) is the best way

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['one','one','one','two','two','two'],
                       'bar': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
                       'baz': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
>>> df
    foo   bar  baz
0   one   A    1
1   one   B    2
2   one   C    3
3   two   A    4
4   two   B    5
5   two   C    6
```

Or
you can load your pair list using

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('ratings.csv')
```

Then

```
>>> df.pivot(index='foo', columns='bar', values='baz')
     A   B   C
one  1   2   3
two  4   5   6
```

Answer (score 1):

you probably have something like

```
m_dict = {'A': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'], 'B': ['bb'], 'C': ['aa']}
```

i would go like this:

```
res = {}
for k, v in m_dict.items():
    res[k] = defaultdict(int)
    for col in v:
        res[k][v] = 1
```

### edit

given your format, it would probably be more in the line of :

```
m_array = [['A', 'aa'], ['A', 'bb'], ['A', 'cc'], ['B', 'bb'], ['C', 'aa']]

res = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
for k, v in m_array:
    res[k][v] = 1
```

which both give:

```
>>> res['A']['aa']
1
>>> res['B']['aa']
0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for `np.unique`. It is not clear what format your data is in, but you need to get two 1-D arrays, one with the keys, another with the values, e.g.:

```
kvp = np.array([['A', 'aa'], ['A', 'bb'], ['A', 'cc'],
                ['B', 'bb'], ['C', 'aa']])

keys, values = kvp.T

rows, row_idx = np.unique(keys, return_inverse=True)
cols, col_idx = np.unique(values, return_inverse=True)

out = np.zeros((len(rows), len(cols)), dtype=np.int)
out[row_idx, col_idx] += 1

>>> out
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0]])
>>> rows
array(['A', 'B', 'C'], 
      dtype='|S2')
>>> cols
array(['aa', 'bb', 'cc'], 
      dtype='|S2')
```

If you have no repeated key-value pairs, this code will work just fine. If there are repetitions, I would suggest abusing scipy's sparse module:

```
import scipy.sparse as sps

kvp = np.array([['A', 'aa'], ['A', 'bb'], ['A', 'cc'],
                ['B', 'bb'], ['C', 'aa'], ['A', 'bb']])

keys, values = kvp.T

rows, row_idx = np.unique(keys, return_inverse=True)
cols, col_idx = np.unique(values, return_inverse=True)

out = sps.coo_matrix((np.ones_like(row_idx), (row_idx, col_idx))).A

>>> out
array([[1, 2, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'A': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'], 'C': ['aa'], 'B': ['bb']}
rows = 'ABC'
cols = ('aa', 'bb', 'cc')
print '   ', ' '.join(cols)
for row in rows:
    print row, ' ',
    for col in cols:
            print ' 1' if col in d.get(row) else ' 0',
    print

>>>     aa bb cc
>>> A    1  1  1
>>> B    0  1  0
>>> C    1  0  0
```